# C++ Homework including pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I can't seem to even understand what is expected of this program. Can anyone help me? I'm a first year student who is absolutely clueless.

Write a program that reads lines of text and appends them to a char buffer[1000]. Read one character at a time by calling cin.get(ch), where ch is a variable of type char. Use input redirection. Stop after reading 1,000 characters. As you read in the text, replace all newline characters '\n' with '\0' terminators. Establish an array char* lines[100], so that the pointers in that array point to the beginnings of the lines in the text. Consider only 100 input lines if the input has more lines. Then display the lines in reverse order, starting with the last input line.
   This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int BUFFER_CAPACITY = 1000;
   const int LINES_CAPACITY = 100; 
   char buffer[BUFFER_CAPACITY];
   char* lines[LINES_CAPACITY];

   int buffer_position = 0;
   int lines_position = 0;

   bool more = true;
   bool newline = true;
   while (more)
   {

      char c = cin.get();
      if (cin.fail()) 
      {
         more = false;
      }
        else if (buffer_position >= BUFFER_CAPACITY) // at (or above) capacity
      { 
         more = false;
      }
      if (newline)
      {
         if (lines_position < LINES_CAPACITY)
         {
            lines[lines_position] = buffer + buffer_position;
            lines_position++;
            newline = false;
         }
         else { more = false; }
      }
      if (more)
      {
         if (c == '\n')
         {
            buffer[buffer_position] = '\0';
            buffer_position++;
            newline = true;
         }
         else
         {
            buffer[buffer_position] = c;
            buffer_position++;
         }
      }
   }

   buffer[BUFFER_CAPACITY - 1] = '\0';

   for (int i = lines_position - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      cout << lines[i] << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you got so far? You can pretty much write the code from reading the problem statement.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Answer (score 2):

1) For starters, one of the whole points of using a higher-level language like "C++" is to get you *away* from dealing with "pointers" (unless absolutely necessary).  Or, for that matter, to get you away from low-level C strings.  So already, this sounds like a poor assignment for an introductory course :(

2) The bit about "change '\n' to '\0'" means that every time you hit "RETURN" - get a new line - in your input, you'll treat it as a separate string in your buffer.

3) You'll need counters for

#/characters input so far (#/times you've done a "cin" and read a character, up to 1000)

#/lines so far (#/times you've read '\n', up to 100)

#/words (#/times you've added '\0' to your buffer)

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like your teacher wants you to read in a block of text and put it in buffer[1000], convert the end of each line of text (which should be the newline character) into a null-terminated string, then put each newly-made string into lines[100] - checking that you don't exceed the bounds of either array.

So your algorithm would be something like

- Make a local char* that points to the start of your new string (first character you read into buffer)
- Read characters into buffer until you find a newline
- Replace the newline with a null
- Store off the char* into lines
- Point the local char* to the next character (start of the new line), and iterate this process until you either hit 1000 characters, 100 lines, or reach the end of your text